# Realtek source code WiFi driver fails after each update

Tags: updates, update-manager, software-sources

I've an issue with Realtek USB WiFi module after each update. The devices works fine, but after Ubuntu installs any new version, the device stops working. When I run `dmesg`, after unplugging and plugging device back, it prints error about version magic mismatch, some parts of the system still expect older version, when software update brought new one.

Searching this and other forums, I found several solutions / workarounds. The one I use is:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

This compiles module from source code, and than I have to unplug the device and plug it back, it starts working again.

But that requires being physically next to the computer, and until it is done - computer is unaccessible from remote.

As I mentioned - this forum has many users facing same problem, but all seems to have to resort to similar manual fixes once update brings new version of the module. Any way to prevent this breakage, and keep device working and machine remotely accessible?

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release details. What I'd do would vary on your release; but assuming it's my release & thus updates occur regularly with kernel upgrades rather common - I'd disable all auto-updates & have a cron job I created do the updates, then re-compile kernel module & restart. It can't unplug & re-plugin, but you're describing a server role which to me wouldn't use wifi anyway.

Comment: I use the `git` version of this module https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au  because 1) It's under active development; 2) It comes with instructions on how to manage the module with `dkms` commands.

Comment: `tree /var/lib/dkms/` please.